Value Look Up based on Multiple Criteria from the same table's rows and columns
I want to create a formula in Columns E and F that will determine who are the agents and nurses on a particular CALL type ROWS.
Example:
I have 2 calls in this sample (Call IDs: 12345 and 67890). They are located in ROW 2 (call ID: 12345) and ROW 6 (Call ID: 67890).
Now, these call IDs have an additional data attributed to them which can be found underneath each Call ID and is categorized as PARTICIPANTS (as can be seen in Column A).
In Column E, I need to determine who are the agents on a particular call ID that is based on a list from Column I, and same for the nurses to Column F based from the list on Column H.
Now if these formulas from Column E and F detects that this row is not a CALL type, then it can be simply ignored.
Here is the tricky part, there is Column D that sorts the PARTICIPANTS (AGENTS/NURSES) in Order for each Call ID. What I want to happen is to get the LAST AGENT before the NURSE as these Last Agents are ALWAYS the one who made a transfer to the nurse on the list.
To help better explain, I need to determine first WHO was the Nurse in each CALL type. As soon as we determine who was the nurse, we can simply get who was the LAST AGENT before them on the table.
In my example, our expected nurse in Column F2 for Call Type: 12345 should be Kim, therefore, our Agent in Column E2 should be Will since Will was the last Agent next to the Nurse on the list for Call Type: 12345.

I hope I was able to explain things clearly!
Thank you all in advanced!
** UPDATED THE SAMPLE SCREENSHOT, REPLACING WILL FROM THE NURSE LIST TO KIM **

These formulas use the TEXTSPLIT and TOCOL functions.
M9: =INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(J9,","),1,MATCH(N9,TEXTSPLIT(J9,","),0)-1)
N9: =TOCOL(IF(TEXTSPLIT(J9,",")=L2:L6,L2:L6,1/0),3)

To select only the rows which are typed as CALL add an IF function
M9: =IF(A9="CALL",INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(J9,","),1,MATCH(N9,TEXTSPLIT(J9,","),0)-1),"")
N9: =IF(A9="CALL",TOCOL(IF(TEXTSPLIT(J9,",")=L2:L6,L2:L6,1/0),3),"")
